# Table attribute

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am creating a code-first model. What should my `[Table]` attribute be? `[Table("PROGRAM_UNIT)"]` or `[Table("dbo.PROGRAM_UNIT")]`?

Table property:

[image]

Table header in DBML:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify the schema name, EF will, by convention, use `dbo`.

For Entity Framework 6 and above, the schema can be changed for all tables by  using the `HasDefaultSchema` method of `DbModelBuilder`:

```
public class CustomContext : DbContext
{
    ...    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MyDefaultDbSchema");
    }
}
```

To change the schema for a specific table  you can use the `Schema` property of `TableAttribute`.

```
[Table("PROGRAM_UNIT", Schema = "schemaName")]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `[Table("PROGRAM_UNIT)"]`